# List and define SMB shares from command-line

Tags: terminal, sharing, smb

In MacOS, is it possible to list and/or define SMB shares at the command-line?

On a Linux machine with Samba, I can use the `testparm` command and the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file.

On Windows it would be the `net share ...` command.

On Mac, I only know the "System Preferences" > "Sharing" GUI. But to check or set these shares on multiple machines, I would like to be able to do it through SSH sessions and the command-line.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On macOS open Terminal and type `man sharing` to review the manual page. You can use `sharing -l` to list AFP/SMB share info. You can add and remove shares using this command line tool.

You can use the `df -h` command or `mount` command to list externally mounted volumes & shares.

Answer (score 3):

There's is a utility called `smbutil` that can be used to view SMB shares

For example:

```
% smbutil view -G //servername.domain
```

Will display the shares that are available via guest access

Comment: That lists locally mounted remote shares, not local directories which are shared.

Comment: Oh..you want *local* directories...I mis-read it.  `sharing -l` is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in [James Brickley's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/405662/14586), there is indeed the ([well hidden](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406161/some-man-pages-missing-from-apropos-whatis-database)) `sharing` command.

It can be used for both listing and managing shares.

To list shares:

```
sharing -l
```

To create a share:

```
sudo sharing -a /Volumes/SomeDisk
```

or, for example to share only over SMB (not AFP), and give the share a different name (here "X_SomeDisk") :

```
sudo sharing -a /Volumes/SomeDisk -S X_SomeDisk -n X_SomeDisk -s 001
```

To remove the share created above:

```
sudo sharing -r X_SomeDisk
```