# Some man pages missing from apropos / whatis database

Tags: terminal, command-line

I used `apropos` and `whatis` to look for some command, but didn't find what I needed. But there is actually a command that does [what I wanted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405658/list-and-define-smb-shares-from-command-line) (it's `sharing`). It does have a man page (`/usr/share/man/man8/sharing.8`), and the `man sharing` command displays it as expected.

However, this command and presumably many others don't appear in any of the 2 whatis databases that I seem to have. The files I have are `/usr/share/man/whatis` and `/usr/local/share/man/whatis`. The `whatis` and `apropos` commands seem to search both.

So I tried to refresh them by running `sudo /usr/libexec/makewhatis`. It did update the `/usr/share/man/whatis` file, but this particular man page (and others I guess) is still missing.

I tried this on 2 different machines. One running High Sierra, and the other running Mojave.

Why are some man pages not listed, and is there anything I can do to have a reliable whatis database?